# Can $g(t) = \infty$ in $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, exponential-function, infinity, riemann-surfaces

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$ be a constant such that $\Re z>0$ (its real part is positive) and $\Im z \neq 0$ (its imaginary part is not zero), then let $f$ and $g$ be functions such that:

$$
\begin{aligned}
f\colon \, \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C} \\
f(t)= e^{zt}
\end{aligned}
\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad
\begin{aligned}
g\colon \, \mathbb{R}\to\hat{\mathbb{C}} \\
g(t)= e^{zt}
\end{aligned}
$$

where $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is the [extended complex plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere) ($\hat{\mathbb{C}} = \mathbb{C}\,\cup\,\left\lbrace \infty \right\rbrace$).

I can easily prove that:

$$ \lim_{t\to\infty} |f(t)| = \lim_{t\to\infty} |e^{zt}| = \lim_{t\to\infty} e^{t\Re z} \to \infty \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \not\exists \lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)$$

But when I want to do the same for $g(t)$:

$$ \lim_{t\to\infty} |g(t)| = \lim_{t\to\infty} |e^{zt}| = \lim_{t\to\infty} e^{t\Re z} \overset{??}{=} \infty \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \exists \lim_{t\to\infty} g(t) = \infty ?$$

**So, I have two existential doubts:**

1. Can a limit (and an expression in general) be equated to infinity, **rigorously**, when working with $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$? This would be to say that $ z=\infty$ is valid in $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$, **rigorously**. Therefore, it is **rigorously** valid to say that (notice the equal symbol):

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} |g(t)| = \infty$$

2. **Does the expression $\lim_{t\to\infty} g(t) = \infty$ is valid**? I ask because, although $\lim_{t\to\infty} |g(t)| = \infty$, it happens that $$\lim_{t\to\infty} e^{i t\Im z} = \lim_{t\to\infty} \cos(t\Im z)+i\sin(t\Im z) $$ is oscillating between all the [complex signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function#Complex_signum). So, I conclude that $$\lim_{t\to\infty} g(t) = \lim_{t\to\infty} |g(t)|\left( \cos(t\Im z)+i\sin(t\Im z) \right) $$ remains oscillating in all possible infinites (in all [directed infinites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_infinity)) and therefore it is **rigorously valid** to say that $$\lim_{t\to\infty} g(t) = \infty$$.

Comment: You would probably be enlightened by looking up the definition of a *pole* vs. an *essential singularity* in complex analysis.

Comment: I've checked, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity, and https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Essential_singular_point. But I can't quite figure it out. Could you enlighten me?

Comment: If you view $\hat C$ as the one-point compactification of $C$, then by definition of its topology, a sequence converges to $\infty$ iff the sequence eventually lies in the complement of every compact set in $C$. The condition $| z | \to \infty$ guarantees this.

Comment: @AlexProvost I understand what you mean, but I still don't see the relationship with $g(t)$. The limit is taken on $t\in\mathbb{R}$, not on $z$ ($z$ is a constant here). Should I treat $t$ as a complex variable and analyze when $|t|\to\infty$? I'm stuck.

Comment: @Fly_NighT But you are interested in the behaviour of $z = g(t)$, which is a complex number. And in terms of sequences, $\lim_{t \to \infty} g(t) = \infty$ means that for any given sequence $t_n \to \infty$, the sequence $z_n = g(t_n) \to \infty$ in the sense described above. (And this is true if $|z_n| \to \infty$.)

Comment: @AlexProvost Oh, I think I got it. What you meant to say is that, as $\lim_{t\to\infty} |g(t)| = \infty$, then it's enough to prove that $\lim_{t\to\infty} g(t) = \infty$ (I confused the $z$ constant I defined with $z=g(t)$, which is what you meant). Correct me if not.

Comment: Yes, proving that $g(t)$ converges to $\infty$ in the extended complex plane is equivalent to showing that its norm goes to $\infty$ in $R$. Alternatively, you could show that $g(t)$ converges to $\infty$ iff $1/g(t)$ converges to $0$; since it is clear that $g(t)$ converges to $0$ iff its norm goes to zero, this yields another way to prove the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, let me post the essence of my comments above as an answer. To talk about limits rigorously, one must clearly understand the underlying topology. The extended complex plane is usually topologized as the one-point compactification of the complex plane. This means that a neighborhood of the point $\infty$ is the complement of a compact (closed and bounded) set in the complex plane. With this in mind, it is easy to see that a function $f:\mathbb R \to \hat {\mathbb C}$ satisfies $f(t) \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$ iff $|f(t)| \to \infty$, which answers your question.